# Python - Select all elements a list of a list

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, python-2.7

I want to write a series of code (it may be func, loop or etc.) to get first 6 chars of each list of every list.

It looks like this:
http://www.mackolik.com/AjaxHandlers/FixtureHandler.aspx?command=getMatches&id=3170&week=1

this is the first list of my list, second can be found here: week=2.

It goes through 11.

In addition to this, each list element of my list differentiates.

Can you help me or give an idea to deal with.

Comment: the second can be found where?

Comment: @bepop I guess it's http://www.mackolik.com/AjaxHandlers/FixtureHandler.aspx?command=getMatches&id=3170&week=2

Comment: Please specify what you've tried and where your problems lie

Comment: some of the items don't even have six characters so how can you get six from each? Do you actually mean the first six elements?

Comment: thanks for your great concerns guys, i need a loop to get each element's 6 digit codes (indicates match id) of list of lists. that is, there is a great list constituting list again but having different length. here it is completely: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10143649/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you you have a wretched multi-level data-in-string-in-list-of-list structure:

```
data = [
    ["[[342212,'21/02',,'MS'], [342276,'21/02',,'MS']]"],
    ["[[342246,'21/02',,'MS']]"]
]
```

and you want to collect `[342212, 342276, 342246]`.

To do this properly you pretty much have to parse each string to an actual data structure; this is complicated by the fact that consecutive commas (`,,`) are not valid Python syntax

```
import ast

def fix_string(s):
                                    # '[,,,]'
    s = s.replace("[,", "[None,")   # '[None,,,]'
    s = s.replace(",,", ", None,")  # '[None, None,,]'
    s = s.replace(",,", ", None,")  # '[None, None, None,]'
    s = s.replace(",]", ", None]")  # '[None, None, None, None]'
    return s

data = [ast.literal_eval(fix_string(s)) for row in data for s in row]
```

which gives us

```
data = [
    [
        [342212,'21/02', None, 'MS'],
        [342276,'21/02', None, 'MS']
    ],
    [
        [342246,'21/02', None, 'MS']
    ]
]
```

then you can collect values like

```
ids = [item[0] for batch in data for item in batch]
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have a list of lists like

```
all_data = [['abcdef', 1213, 12.5], ['ghijkl', 'bla', 'foo', 'baz']]
first_items = [data[0] for data in all_data]
print(first_items)
```

If you have everything only as a string, each sublist is dived by `],[` and there are no other `[]` brackets, you could:

```
all_data_raw = "[[342174,'25/02','MS',1655,'Vefa',537,'Centone Karagümrük',,4,1,0,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,'0 - 0',0],[342265,'25/02','MS',649,'Beykozspor 1908',3,'Beşiktaş',,4,1,0,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,'0 - 0',0]"
all_data = all_data_raw[2:-2].split('],[')
first_items = [data[:6] for data in all_data]
print(first_items)
```

In case you want to do more with the data than that, you should do a proper import into objects.

Comment: Could somebody explain the downvote to avoid the mistake I’ve made?

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, i didn't give this negative. Would you like to see my solution which is so similar with yours: <br/> maclar = list(scrape_page(y) for y in hafta)
        maclar2 = [m[0][0][2:-2].replace("],[",";") for m in maclar]
        maclar3=maclar2.split(';')
        macvektor=[d[0:6] for d in maclar3] <br/> but it did not work because of it does not iterate recursively.